# axios return POST response outside function - Typescript

Tags: typescript, axios

I'm trying to write a function in Typescript that returns a token value. Everything works perfectly up until the point where the token value is simply logged into the console and not returned.

```
  createToken(): string{
      axios.post(BASE_URL, body, { headers })
      .then(async (response) => {
      let responseData = response.data;
      let getToken = JSON.stringify(responseData);
      const obj = JSON.parse(getToken);
      //VALUE IS LOGGED IN THE CONSOLE, HOW CAN IT BE RETURNED??
      console.log(obj.access_token);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      })
  return 'TOKEN SHOULD BE RETURNED HERE';
  }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this which you can **see in the first answer post**

```
async createToken(): Promise<string> {
    const { data } = await axios.post(BASE_URL, body, { headers })
    return data.access_token
}
```

But, if you don’t like to use await,
You can do like this...

```
async createToken(): Promise<string> {
      return axios.post(BASE_URL, body, { headers })
      .then( (response) => {
      let responseData = response.data;
      let getToken = JSON.stringify(responseData);
      const obj = JSON.parse(getToken);
      //VALUE IS LOGGED IN THE CONSOLE, HOW CAN IT BE RETURNED??
      console.log(obj.access_token);
      return obj.access_token;
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }
```

Comment: Hi,

This still resolves in a Promise { <pending> } output and is not returning a string

Comment: If you get the token from the external system (axios), then there is no way that you can do without promise. The function which calls createToken function has to put await to get the token string.

Comment: Like this. ‘const response = await createToken()’

Comment: Hello Kugesh,

Again no luck

`async createToken(): Promise<string> {
    const { data } = await axios.post(BASE_URL, body, { headers })  
    return data.access_token
}

  async getToken():Promise<string>{
  const response = await this.createToken();
    return response
}`

When I run the functions again a Promise {<pending>} is returned

`let auth = new Authentication();
console.log(auth.getToken());`

Comment: For this we need to provide await in front of  of getToken call
   console.log(await auth.getToken());

Also, there is a change in the solution which I suggested. I removed async in then function. You can refer that in original solution I wrote.

Answer (score 0):

Your `.then()` function runs after the `post` returns. Since that is asynchronous, it may (and almost always will) be after the function has already returned.

If you want Javascript to wait for it, you need to use the [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) format instead.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense, however how exactly will the value be returned in the function?

Answer (score 0):

The token cannot be returned because by the time it is retrieved in the callback, the `createToken` function has already finished executing. Consider rewriting your function using [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) syntax to make it return a Promise:

```
async createToken(): Promise<string> {
    const { data } = await axios.post(BASE_URL, body, { headers })
    return data.access_token
}
```

Comment: Hello,

Thanks for the comment, however this unfortuntely doesn't work in my case since the returned type is a promise and I need the returned value to be a string

Comment: Yep; when you invoke an async operation like `axios.post`, you're necessarily locked in to dealing with the data asynchronously. You will need to await this function as well in another async function like `const token = await createToken()`, or handle it in a callback with `createToken().then((token) => ...)`.